Can't get image_gallery_sd.py to work on my inky frame 7.3, but sd card itself works, picture displaying too
I tried to run image_gallery_sd.py. It results in the following error (I have named my pictures 0001.jpg through to 0005.jpg):
MPY: soft reboot
Displaying /sd/0005.jpg
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 63, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 44, in display_image
RuntimeError: JPEG: could not read file/buffer.

I have run the sd_test.py successfully. And I've successfully displayed the same picture but directly from the pico's root, not from the sd card.
So both the sd card seems to work and displaying this specific picture (and others). But not displaying a picture from the sd card.

what have you tried so far ?
the question needs sufficient code for a minimal reproducible example

I ran the code that is behind the link in gitbhub, just using the file names on my sd card. To verify that the sd card is connected, I ran the code in the other link. And to verify the files are OK, I displayed them while they were saved to the inky frame, not the sd card.
